# trouble getting the contents of a YouTube Subscription

Tags: c#, youtube-api

So far I have

```
YouTubeRequestSettings mySettings;
YouTubeRequest myRequestFeed;
mySettings = new YouTubeRequestSettings("myApp", devKey, userName, password);
myRequestFeed = new YouTubeRequest(settings);
Feed<Subscription> mySubscriptionFeed = myRequestFeed.GetSubscriptionsFeed(null);
List<string> lst = new List<string>();
foreach (var sub in mySubscriptionFeed.Entries) {
    //I can iterate over each subscription and get name, ect.
    // I can't seem to figure out how to get the videos in each subscription.
SubscriptionEntry entry = sub.SubscriptionEntry;
    Feed<Video> videoFeed = entry.???
}
```

for playlists, there is

```
Feed<PlayListMember> video_list = myRequestFeed.GetPlaylist(pl);
```

but there seems to be no similar function for retrieveing the subscription contents.

In the old API (1.something) it was done with

```
string feedURI = SubscritpionEntry.FeedLink.Href;
query = new YouTubeQuery(feedURI);
```

but FeedLink is no longer there.

In [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol#Retrieving_subscriptions), they state

"The content tag in each entry specifies the URL for retrieving videos for the subscription."

//and in [this documentation](http://31stentourage-nvk.appspot.com/code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/migration.html)

"Modify your code to check the value of the  tag instead of the  tag in playlists feed entries and subscriptions feed entries."

Except that

```
SubscriptionEntry entry = sub.SubscriptionEntry;
entry.content.Src and entry.content.AbsoluteURL
```

are the only things filled in, and nothing I seem to do with them produces the underlying list of items. I have to be missing something obvious, but I can't see it.

Comment: Could you please clarify what you're trying to retrieve? Do you want to get the list of all the channels that the authenticated account is subscribed to? Or a list of the most recent videos that have been uploaded in the channels?